# Detect subsethood of rows in `data.table`

Tags: r, data.table

Given two data tables, `a` and `b`, how can I check which rows of `a` are also in `b`? The output should be a logical vector with length equal to `a`'s number of rows, and in the same order as the rows of `a`, similar to `%in%` for vectors.

For example, here's a simple-minded, non-vectorized implementation. Presumably there's a faster way to do it.

```
library(data.table)

dt.in = function(a, b)
    sapply(1 : nrow(a), function(i)
        nrow(fintersect(a[i], b)) > 0)

stopifnot(identical(
   dt.in(
       data.table(
           c1 = c("c", "1", "c", "F", "p", "c", "r"),
           c2 = c("C", "B", "5", "f", "P", "C", "S")),
       data.table(c1 = letters, c2 = LETTERS)),
   c(T, F, F, F, T, T, F)))
```

Comment: What defines if a row is in both data frames?  All values of all columns are identical or just a subset ?  Is position - ie row number - important?

Comment: @Limey All values of all columns. The order of columns is important, but the order of rows in `b` is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this can be achieved by joining on *all* columns:

```
library(data.table)
# sample data 
dt1 <- data.table(
  c1 = c("c", "1", "c", "F", "p", "c", "r"),
  c2 = c("C", "B", "5", "f", "P", "C", "S"))
dt2 <- data.table(c1 = letters, c2 = LETTERS)

stopifnot(identical(names(dt1), names(dt2)))
!is.na(dt2[dt1, on = names(dt1), which = TRUE])
```

> ```
> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
> ```

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68412135/detect-subsethood-of-rows-in-data-table/68412448#comment120905624_68412135), the OP has pointed out that *the order of columns is important*. For the sake of simplicity, I have assumed that the names of the columns of both datasets are identical.

`which = TRUE` asks to return a vector of row indices of `df1` which have a match in `df2` or `NA` otherwise. This is converted into a logical vector as requested.

---

If the columns names are *not identical* and the match is solely based on position, this can be solved programmatically, e.g.

```
# modified sample data 
dt1 <- data.table(
  c1 = c("c", "1", "c", "F", "p", "c", "r"),
  c2 = c("C", "B", "5", "f", "P", "C", "S"))
dt2 <- data.table(v1 = letters, v2 = LETTERS)

!is.na(dt2[dt1, on = c(paste(names(dt2), names(dt1), sep = "==")), which = TRUE])
```

Note that the columns of `df2` are now named `v1`, `v2` instead of `c1`, `c2`.
The join clause (`on =`) has become

```
"v1==c1" "v2==c2"
```

Comment: Well done. I hadn't known about `which` in indices.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

population <- data.frame(c1=letters, c2=LETTERS)
sample <- data.frame(
            c1 = c("c", "1", "c", "F", "p", "c", "r"),
            c2 = c("C", "B", "5", "f", "P", "C", "S"))

sample %>% 
  left_join(population %>% add_column(InPopulation=TRUE)) %>% 
  pull(InPopulation) %>% 
  replace_na(FALSE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

This joins on all columns that the data frames have in common.  "in common" is determined by name, not position.